# How to play and chain html5 videos in IOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, video, safari, html5-video

I try to chain 2 videos :
when the first has ended, the second start to play automatically.

It works in Chrome or Firefox in W10 and Ubuntu
but I can't find the way to make it works in IOS : Safari or Chrome or Firefox.
It's like "Video_2.play();" doesn't fire inside "Video_1.addEventListener(...)" in IOS.

What did I miss ?

```js
var Video_1 = document.getElementById("ID_Video_1");
var Video_2 = document.getElementById("ID_Video_2");


Video_1.addEventListener('loadedmetadata',function() {
    alert("Can start playing video Video_1");
    Video_1.play();
});

Video_2.addEventListener('loadedmetadata',function() {
    alert("Can start playing video Video_2");
});

Video_1.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
    alert("Video_1 ENDED");
    Video_2.style.visibility = "visible";
    Video_1.style.visibility = "hidden";
    Video_2.play();
    alert("Video_2.play();");
    });
```

```css
#DIV_video {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 430px;
    height: 270px;
    }

.CLASS_Video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#ID_Video_1 {
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 1;
    }

#ID_Video_2 {
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 2;
    }
```

```html
<div id="DIV_video">

<video id="ID_Video_2" playsinline class="CLASS_Video" width="150" src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"></video>
<video id="ID_Video_1" playsinline class="CLASS_Video" width="150" src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4"></video>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer :

https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/

And now I think there is no solution for me in IOS even if it's Chrome or Firefox...